# Basic Authorization Credentials will not show up in Scapy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, scapy, packet

> Note: The scapy layer 'http' is installed with `pip install scapy-http`

I have the following code that prints the value of the Authorization value in the HTTP Request layer:

```
import sys
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers import http
interface = 'wlan0'
def packet(p):
    tcp = p.getlayer('TCP')
    if tcp:
        req = p.getlayer('HTTP Request')
        if req:
            auth = req.Authorization
            if auth:
                print(auth)
try:
    sniff(iface=interface,store=0,filter="tcp and port 80",prn=packet)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(1)
```

This is supposed to print the credentials showed in [this wire shark screenshot](https://ibb.co/hN6yCH), but it only prints `b'Basic YWRtaW46RjByZXZlciQ='`. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Authorization` header value is, in you case, exactly `b'Basic YWRtaW46RjByZXZlciQ='`. This means the basic authentication scheme has been used, and the value is `<username>:<password>`, base64 encoded (`admin` and `F0rever$` in your case).

You could do:

```
[...]
            auth = req.Authorization
            if auth and auth.startswith(b'Basic '):
                uname, passw = base64_bytes(auth.split(None, 1)[1]).split(b':', 1)
                print("Username: %r, password: %r" % (uname.decode(), passw.decode()))
```

Comment: What is `base64_bytes`? I'm getting an undefined error

Comment: Update to scapy's latest version from https://github.com/secdev/scapy (`base64_bytes` has been introduced recently).

Comment: I don't know, how did you install Scapy in the first place? If it was with pip, try `pip install --upgrade scapy`.